# FindAll lambda expression on boolean types

Tags: c#, list, lambda, findall

I have an intriguing question.
considering this line of code :

```
List<bool> selectedValues = allValues.FindAll(x => x);
```

where `allValues` is a list of `boolean`s.
Why is that `FindAll()`  finds all `true` values in `selectedValues` list but not all the `false` one?

To my knowledge, we are assessing the same value in (`x => x`). So if you assess `False` and `False` (or `False` goes to `False`), shouldn't that be `true` as well?

why is it that if x = true, (x=>x) == true,
but if x = false, (x=>x) == false.

my understanding is that :

1. false equals false (that makes it true)
2. true equals true (that makes it true as well)
   Why is it that 1) is not true

I rewrote the same syntax as :

```
List<bool> selectedHobbies = allHobbies.FindAll(hobby => x.Equals(true));
```

The second one is more understanding to me. But I cannot get a grip on the first syntax.
because the second syntax actually checks `x` with another value

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand how lambda expressions work so you should do some research on that.

`(x => x)` is not comparing `x` to `x`. The `=>` is not a comparison operator. The first `x` is simply declaring a variable to refer to the current item in the list, much as you would do in a `foreach` loop. A lambda that compared `x` to `x` would look like this:

```cs
(x => x == x)
```

In that case, you'd get every item in the list because every item is equal to itself. That lambda is evaluating the Boolean expression to the right of the `=>` and filtering based on the result. Items for which that expression evaluates to `true` will be included and the others will be excluded. That lambda is equivalent to this:

```cs
(x => x == true)
```

If `x` is `true` then the expression (which is just `x`) is `true` and that item will be included. If `x` is `false` then the expression is `false` and that item will be excluded. In words, this:

```cs
allValues.FindAll(x => x)
```

is saying "find all items in `allValues` where the expression `x` for item `x` is `true`".

Answer (score 0):

In `x => x`, you are essentially evaluating the expression `x`, like you would have done for `x.Equals(true)`. Therefore, it will only pick the values where this expression evaluates to true i.e. all true values in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

`FindAll` acts a filter. It keeps only that elements where the provided `Predicate` is evaluated to true. Since your source collection contains booleans that's why `x => x` is enough to act as a `Predicate` (a function that returns a `boolean`).

If you would want to filter for the false values then `x => !x` could be used.